# How can i add an account to Windows Phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, settings, account

I'm new in developing applications for Windows Phone 8. Can I add custom account from my application (to Settings => email+accounts)? Thank you.[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Are you attempting to do this in code or are you asking generally? Please ask a question

Comment: I am asking generally. Sorry, i am new in english language too =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible to add an account programatically with the current SDK.